# UI View Controller crashes after interruption

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, interrupt

Given the multitasking of iOS I thought it wouldn't be a pain to pause and resume my app, by pressing the home button or due to a phone call, but for a particular view controller it crashes.

The navigation bar is working fine i.e. when I tap "Back" it's ok, but if I try to tap controls of the displayed UI View Controller then I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.. =/

Please find the code of my problematic View Controller below. I'm not very sure about it myself, because I used loadView to build its View. However apart from this interruption problem it works fine.

StoreViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol StoreViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)DirectionsClicked:(double)lat:(double)lon;
@end

@interface StoreViewController : UIViewController 
{
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    NSString *description;  
    NSString *imageURL;
    short rating;
    NSString *storeType;
    NSString *offerType;

    UIImageView *imageView;
    UILabel *descriptionLabel;

    id<StoreViewDelegate> storeViewDel;
}

@property (nonatomic) double latitude;
@property (nonatomic) double longitude;
@property (nonatomic) short rating;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *imageURL;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *storeType;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *offerType;
@property (assign) id<StoreViewDelegate> storeViewDel;

@end
```

StoreViewController.m

```
#import "StoreViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface StoreViewController()

-(CGSize) calcLabelSize:(NSString *)string withFont:(UIFont *)font  maxSize:(CGSize)maxSize;

@end

@implementation StoreViewController

@synthesize storeViewDel, longitude, latitude, description, imageURL, rating, offerType, storeType;

- (void)mapsButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
}

- (void)loadView 
{
    UIView *storeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];

    // Colours
    UIColor *lightBlue = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:(189.0f / 255.0f) 
                                              green:(230.0f / 255.0f) 
                                               blue:(252.0f / 255.0f) alpha:1.0f];

    UIColor *darkBlue = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:(28.0f/255.0f) 
                                                green:(157.0f/255.0f) 
                                                 blue:(215.0f/255.0f) 
                                                alpha:1.0f];

    // Layout
    int width = self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width;
    int height = self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height;
    float firstRowHeight = 100.0f;
    int margin = width / 20;
    int imgWidth = (width - 3 * margin) / 2;

    // Set ImageView 
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(margin, margin, imgWidth, imgWidth)];
    CALayer *imgLayer = [imageView layer];
    [imgLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [imgLayer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    [imgLayer setBorderWidth:4.0f];
    [imgLayer setBorderColor:[lightBlue CGColor]];
    // Load default image
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"thumb-null.png"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [imageView setImage:image];

    [storeView addSubview:imageView];

    // Set Rating
    UIImageView *ratingView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3 * width / 4 - 59.0f, 
                                                                        margin, 
                                                                        118.0f,
                                                                        36.0f)];
    UIImage *ratingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bb-rating-0.png"];
    [ratingView setImage:ratingImage];
    [ratingImage release];

    [storeView addSubview:ratingView];

    // Set Get Directions button
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3 * width / 4 - 71.5f, 
                                                               36.0f + 2*margin, 
                                                               143.0f, 63.0f)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(mapsButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIImage *mapsImgUp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bb-maps-up.png"];
    [btn setImage:mapsImgUp forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mapsImgUp release];
    UIImage *mapsImgDown = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bb-maps-down.png"];
    [btn setImage:mapsImgDown forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [mapsImgDown release];

    [storeView addSubview:btn];
    [btn release];

    // Set Description Text
    UIScrollView *descriptionView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 
                                                                                   imgWidth + 2 * margin, 
                                                                                   width, 
                                                                                   height - firstRowHeight)];
    descriptionView.backgroundColor = lightBlue;
    CGSize s = [self calcLabelSize:description withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f] maxSize:CGSizeMake(width, 9999.0f)];
    descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(margin, margin, width - 2 * margin, s.height)];
    descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f];
    descriptionLabel.textColor = darkBlue;
    descriptionLabel.text = description;
    descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = lightBlue;

    [descriptionView addSubview:descriptionLabel];
    [storeView addSubview:descriptionView];
    [descriptionLabel release];

    [lightBlue release];
    [darkBlue release];

    self.view = storeView;
    [storeView release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
[imageView release];
    [descriptionLabel release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Any suggestions ?

Thank you,

F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I released some UIImages that were never allocated. Erasing the following lines solved my issue:

```
[ratingImage release];
[mapsImgUp release];
[mapsImgDown release];
```

F.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at your crash report, get an idea of where it's crashing, and help us help you by posting the relevant code if it is not clear to you what is causing the crash. We may be able to help you further, but we need you to do some pre-requisite work first, like trying to solve it yourself with the appropriate information at hand. Now that you know what to look for, please, go forth and unicorn!

Comment: lol! Jer thank you for the immediate response. I posted my code in my question; also the crash report is the message in the Console? Apart from Program received signal EXC BAD ACCESS and 'Unable to read symbols..' there's nothing else there.. Thank you! F.

Comment: If you're running on the device, go to organizer, click on your device, then tap on device logs. Find the application / date combo when you had the crash (or reproduce it and take note of the time). The stack trace there in the appropriate thread that crashed, is important.